# MapServer: How to define connection string outside of mapfile?

Tags: postgresql, mapserver

Is there a possibility in MapServer to store the connection string in an external file and reference it in the mapfile?

I have basic Postgres connection strings like this:

```
CONNECTION "user=user_of_db password=password_of dbname=name_of_db host=host_of_db"
```

I want to separate the passwords from my mapfiles so that anyone with access to the mapfile cannot directly access the connected databases.

Comment: At least if should be possible to encrypt the credentials https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/1792.

Comment: Or you can put the connection string into another file that it read into the main mapfile with INCLUDE. Perhaps you can find a way to limit the access to the included mapfile.